# PHP 5.4 $_GET Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, get, undefined, notice

this Code works in PHP 5.3, but not in PHP 5.4 > Error Notice: Undefined index:

```
//station
$station = $_GET['station'];

if (!$station)
    $station = 'main';



//base path
```

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the setting of your error_reporting, but you should always check if the 'station' was already set through the http(s) like
www.example.com?station=piccadily

```
if (isset($_GET['station']) && $station = $_GET['station'])
else $station = 'main;
```

or simplify it to:

```
$station = isset($_GET['station']) ? $_GET['station'] : 'main';
```

since PHP7 you may write with coalesce operator:

```
$station = $_GET['station'] ?? 'main';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $station = $_GET['station'];
    error_reporting(0);
    if ( isset ( $station ) ) :
        $station = 'main';
    else :
        $action = 'null';
    endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: Same Player Script 
1 Server Centos 6.7 PHP 5.3  http://195.154.68.186/ works
2. Server Centos 7 PHP 5.4  http://37.59.14.143/player/index.php not load swf file

Comment: I don't understand that code, b/c you'll get the same notice at the second line, if the error_reporting is set to ALL (0) before executing the code. What's $action?

Comment: Tom K. if you want I can send you the script. to test

Comment: @Ambassador: I do not understand the code of Fernando, did you already tried the <code> `$station = isset($_GET['station']) ? $_GET['station'] : 'main';`</code>   You may send me the script if you want.. : oe6tkt (AT) gmx.at

Comment: hi i have send the script